# angular 2: get FormGroup by FormControl

Tags: angular, form-control

can i get the FormGroup - the parent of the FormControl that i have?
like this:

```
    onBlur(formControl: FormControl) {
    var formGroup = formControl.parent // a FormGroup has the FormControl
    if (formControl.dirty) {

        console.log(formControl);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I currently have angular 5, but I'm sure on angular 4 it also worked like this:

`formControl.parent`

In my code, for example, I'm getting other control (by name) from the same group with:

`formControl.parent.get(neighbourName)`

Answer (score 5):

You can't access the parent of FormControl (see: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/5635). But you can access the parent using Model-Driven Forms.

```
 constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {

 this.form = fb.group({
   name: [],
   address: fb.group({
     city: ['', Validators.required],
     street: ['', Validators.required],
     zipCode: '',
     year: 2016
   }),
   groupDates: fb.group({
     fromDate_g: [''],
     toDate_g: ['', Validators.required]
   }, {validator: Validators.required}),
   dates: fb.group({
     fromDate: '',
     toDate: ''
   })
  });

  let datesGroup =  this.form.controls['dates'] as FormGroup;


}
```

Comment: There is a pull request for that. Tell me what do you need this for. I've managed to make some workarounds for mechanisms which needed FontControl parent access.

Comment: i develop an app with auto-save forms. i.e. any control that changed by user, is send to server immediately.
i prefer to make an generic function to do it, so my approach is to store inside the FormGroup (model-driven) some metadata, then sent the FormControl to the function ,the function make the right decision whether to send the update server.
This function specializes exclusively in updating information to the server, and I prefer to teach my team passing one parameter to the function, In order to reduce errors and inconsistency.

Comment: Ok. So subscribe on observable provided by Control (it may be a group) and then pass the value to the function. I think it's a clean way of doing it.

Comment: I see in source code of FormControl the  `_parent` property what is private? What consideration?

Answer (score 1):

It seems possible, but against the conventions.

```
 getParentForm(formControl: FormControl): FormGroup {
    return formControl['_parent'];
}
```